# Eloquent: transform a sql request

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Someone could help me to transform this SQL query with Eloquent please :

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT date FROM `non_working_days` where YEAR(date)="2021" AND city IN ('Paris','NewYork');
```

At the moment I have this :

```php
$city = ['Paris','NewYork'];

$data = Model::query()
  ->distinct()
  ->whereYear('date', $year)
  ->whereIn('city', $city)
  ->get();
```

But this does not eliminate duplication, I can have the date 01/01/2021 repeated for example.

Comment: did you try ```->select('date')``` after distinct? You can see the generated query if you add ->dd() before the ->get()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to eloquent you can use the below query which yields

```
$city = ['Paris','NewYork'];
    $data = NonWorkingDays::query()
    ->select('DATE')
      ->whereYear('date', 2021)
      ->whereIn('city', $city)
      ->groupBy('date')
      ->distinct()->get();
```

alternatively you can use Query Builder approach

````
$city = ['Paris','NewYork'];
$year =2021;
    $data = DB::table('non_working_days')
    ->select('DATE')
      ->whereYear('date', $year)
      ->whereIn('city', $city)
      ->groupBy('date')
      ->distinct()->get();
 ```
````

Answer (score 0):

you can try groupBy():

```
$city = ['Paris','NewYork'];

$data = Model::query()
  ->whereYear('date', $year)
  ->whereIn('city', $city)
  ->groupBy('date')
  ->get();
```